# 'div' inside 'table'

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Is a *div* inside a table allowed or not according to W3C?

Comment: Have you looked in the specification, or tried it out in the validator?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>content</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!

Answer (score 40):

You can't put a `div` *directly* inside a `table`, like this:

```
<!-- INVALID -->
<table>
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
</table>
```

Putting a `div` inside a `td` or `th` element is fine, however:

```
<!-- VALID -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        Hello World
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: u didnt mention <tr> =P

Comment: @ I don't think you can use a `div`  directly inside a `tr` as well

Answer (score 19):

You can put *div* tags inside a *td* tag, but not directly inside a *table* or *tr* tag.

Examples:

This works:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>This will work.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

This does not work:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <div> this does not work. </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Nor does this work:

```html
<table>
  <div> this does not work. </div>
</table>
```

Comment: This solution works, but it seems that when , "div", elements are used as children of, "td", elements, the specified width and height of the, "div", is ignored.

Comment: Re *"does not work"*: Can you be more specific? What happens?

Answer (score 9):

While you can, as others have noted here, put a DIV inside a TD (not as a direct child of TABLE), I strongly advise against using a DIV as a child of a TD. Unless, of course, you're a fan of headaches.

There is little to be gained and a whole lot to be lost, as there are many cross-browser discrepancies regarding how widths, margins, borders, etc., are handled when you combine the two. I can't tell you how many times I've had to clean up that kind of markup for clients because they were having trouble getting their HTML to display correctly in this or that browser.

Then again, if you're not fussy about how things look, disregard this advice.

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed as *TD* can contain inline *and* block lements.

Here you can find it in the reference: http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/td/#td-contains

Comment: The is (effectively) broken: *"This webpage was generated by the domain owner using Sedo Domain Parking."*