# Can someone tell me why my div style doesn't work please

Tags: html, css

My id  #kiwi doesn't seem to work. Could anyone explain me why it is not working? I've been searching for some help but couldn't find it. It doesn't even work when I try to class it too.

```
<head>
    <title>this is the title sucker</title>

    <style>
        #kiwi {background-color:green;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>      
    <table border="1">

        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Statistics</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="1">Car model name</th>
            <th colspan="0">Vegetables</th>
            <th>Delicious Fruits</th>
        </tr>


        <div id="kiwi">
        <tr>
            <td>Jaguar</td>
            <td>Tomato</td>
            <td>Kiwi</td>
        </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BMW</td>
            <td>Potato</td>
            <td>Apples</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AUDI</td>
            <td>Cabbage</td>
            <td>Watermelon</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should assign the id to `<tr>` tag and not put it in a div

This works:

```
<head>
    <title>this is the title sucker</title>
    <style>
        #kiwi {background-color:green;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>      
    <table border="1">

        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Statistics</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="1">Car model name</th>
            <th colspan="0">Vegetables</th>
            <th>Delicious Fruits</th>
        </tr>

        <tr id="kiwi">
            <td>Jaguar</td>
            <td>Tomato</td>
            <td>Kiwi</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>BMW</td>
            <td>Potato</td>
            <td>Apples</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AUDI</td>
            <td>Cabbage</td>
            <td>Watermelon</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact it does work. It is the matter of `div` content.

Instead of

```
    <div id="kiwi">
    <tr>
        <td>Jaguar</td>
        <td>Tomato</td>
        <td>Kiwi</td>
    </div>
    </tr>
```

Try for example:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Jaguar</td>
        <td>Tomato</td>
        <td><div id="kiwi">Kiwi</div></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As it turns out, you can use a `div` inside a `tr` as well. So you can either place it inside the `td` tag, as shown below. Or if you want to color the whole row, you can put id on 'tr' itself, as suggested by others here.

There are a few things there. First of all, you cannot put a`<div>` directly inside a `<table>` tag. You have to place it inside a `<th>` or `<td>` tag.

See more here : [div inside table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974573/div-inside-table)

Also, you `<div>` tag is opened before `<tr>`, but closed after it, which is not correct. Always open and close tags in correct order.

You can do something like this:

```
<tr>
        <td>Jaguar</td>
        <td>Tomato</td>
        <td><div id="#kiwi">Kiwi</div></td>
</tr>
```