# Why does the div tag not stay in the correct place?

Tags: html, css

In my code, the div class="userData" wraps around tbody However, looking at the source code in Chrome, the div goes above the table. I ultimately want to make the table body scrollable with the table header staying in place.

```
  <!--details block-->
  <div class="details">
    <div class="field-top">
      <p>
        Details
        <span style="float:right;">
            Record Count:<span id="recordCount">0</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>

      <table class="details" id="userTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id="firstName">First Name
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="firstNameUpArrow" onclick="sortFirstName('ascending')" style="display: none">
                  arrow_upward
                </span>
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="firstNameDownArrow" onclick="sortFirstName('descending')" style="display: none">
                  arrow_downward
                </span>
            </th>
            <th id="lastName">Last Name
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="lastNameUpArrow" onclick="sortLastName('ascending')" style="display: none">
                arrow_upward
              </span>
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="lastNameDownArrow" onclick="sortLastName('descending')" style="display: none">
                arrow_downward
              </span>
            </th>
            <th id="'title">Title
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="titleUpArrow" onclick="sortTitle('ascending')" style="display: none">
                arrow_upward
              </span>
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="titleDownArrow" onclick="sortTitle('descending')" style="display: none">
                arrow_downward
              </span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <div class="userData">
          <tbody id="userTable"><p>test</p></tbody>
        </div>
      </table>
  </div>
```

here is the relevant css

```
div.details{ /*details block*/
  flex:3;
}

div.userData{
  height: 743px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  margin-top: 0%;
  border: none;
}
```

this is what the code looks like in the console
[image]

Comment: A div element has to be inside a th (table header cell) or td (table data cell). Otherwise it is booted to outside of the table, like your image. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974573/div-inside-table

Comment: thank you !  I was able to fix this